# Problem: Armature Twitches at Its Own Volition During Posing

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, transforms

When i move any bone of my armature, which is applied to a character, mesh moves accordingly, but then mesh together with bone move a little to the side and sometimes mesh even changes its shape on its own. Why? What do I do to stop this from happening? I have been animating my character for quite some time and I've never seen this happening, it only started recently. [image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: How can anyone know if you don't show/detail your setup, at least a minimum?

Comment: well I added some images if they help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to apply the scale location and rotation . You can do that by clicking Ctrl + a then apply all what I stated above . IF that still doesn’t work then in edit mode select all vertices and click ctrl+n . If all this doesn’t work then I suggest clearing the parents of the rig and the mesh by click alt+p and parenting them again .

Comment: Thank you, Ctrl+N did a trick for me.  What does it do though? Can I see it changing some options somewhere?

Comment: It makes the faces outside or inverted on the right way and yes you can the changes if u click t on the bottom you will find an option that says inside most of the time you don’t need to click that since in most cases you want the faces facing outside not inside